# How to delete "Done" Notifications?

Tags: github

[image: Screenshot]

I have lots of old and useless notifications when I mark them done they go to "done" section (obviously) but I couldn't find a way to remove them completely. How can I remove these old notifications from my life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not seem  a way to manually clear out the `Done` section.

[The documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-and-triaging-notifications/managing-notifications-from-your-inbox) simply mentions:

> Notifications marked as `Done` are saved for 5 months.

So they are cleared out eventually, but not immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I run this script in the developer console to clear out the inbox.

Remove the octicon-x if you don't want to miss failed workflows.

```js
const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('notifications-list')[0];
  let iterationMatches = 0;
  ["octicon-issue-closed", "octicon-git-merge", "octicon-git-pull-request-closed", "octicon-x", "octicon-tag", "octicon-git-pull-request-draft"].forEach(function (cl) {
     
   Array.from(parent.getElementsByClassName(cl)).forEach(function (el) {
      el.closest("li") && el.closest("li").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();
      iterationMatches++;
    });
  });
  parent.querySelectorAll('button[data-hotkey="e"]')[0].click();

  matches = iterationMatches;

  if (matches === 0) {
    console.log('No more notifications to dismiss');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 4000);
```